# Java text file read from specific character and put in different TextField

Tags: file, text, jtextfield

I am trying to read from a text file and insde the text file is :

```
champ[34] = "ABC"; w1[34] = "Nick"; w2[34] = "SAM"; w3[34] = "Ronald";  
w4[34] = "Richeal"; w5[34] = "George"; w6[34] = "Sarah"; w7[34] = "Karin";  
w8[34] = "Chris"; w9[34] = "Christina";
```

and I have 10 Textfields. I want to read the Text file and when the reader check if there is a ("), then I will start putting the ABC to the first textField, and then the second textField will put the Nick...

and also in the text file, It only has one line but when you read it, it will appear with 3 lines which I set it with "\n" when I was saving to the text file.

Is there anyway to do that??

Answer (score 0):

Read all the file content to one string variable.
Then use regex to get the matching sub strings.
Pattern should be some thing like: **get shortest text between =(can have zero to many spaces)" and "(can have zero to many spaces);**

Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html for more details.

e.g:

```
 String str = "champ[34] = \"ABC\"; w1[34] = \"Nick\"; w2[34] = \"SAM\"; w3[34] = \"Ronald\"; w4[34] = \"Richeal\"; "
            + "w5[34] = \"George\"; w6[34] = \"Sarah\"; w7[34] = \"Karin\"; w8[34] = \"Chris\"; w9[34] = \"Christina\";";


    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("=\\s*\".*?\"\\s*;");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
        System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end() + " ");
        System.out.println("group:" + matcher.group());
    }
```